# Angular: can't access array in object

Tags: angularjs

im trying to access to array in object, but no success.
read other posts and answers here, still, cant do it.

this is my obj: activeInvoice

```
balance_due:
"-72.26"
customer_id
:
"4"
customerpm_id
:
"1244"
date
:
"2017-03-02 04:23:18"
id:
"10334"
invoice_data:
"{"subtotal":72.26,"items":[{"storeid":"148","title":"MONTEBELLO","qty":1,"price":"1.9900","type":"payment"},{"storeid":"149","title":"Gold Elements - Store","qty":1,"price":"66.2900","type":"payment"},{"storeid":"860","title":"Gold Elements - Cart","qty":1,"price":"1.9900","type":"payment"},{"storeid":"1805","title":"Repeat the Heat 2","qty":1,"price":"1.9900","type":"payment"},{"storeid":"2867","title":"office","qty":1,"price":"0.0000","type":"payment"}]}"
invoice_type
:
"monthly_subscription"
status
:
"0"
```

this is my HTML

```
<table class="table dark">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>Price (USD)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="invoice in activeInvoice.invoice_data">
    <td class="text-center"></td>
    <td class="text-center" ng-repeat="data in invoice.items">{{data.title}}</td>
    <td class="text-center"></td>
    <td class="text-center"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

trying to access invoice_data items, and im getting `[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater` error
tried with track by, no success.
thank you

Comment: use valid javascript and try to format your code...

Comment: activeInvoice.invoice_data is JSON object not array
`<tr ng-repeat="invoice in activeInvoice.invoice_data">` this line is not correct i guess

Comment: this is how i get it from DB

Comment: Hitmands can you please explane little more?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you have some record that are the same... so you need to `track` your repeat by some unique field... something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="invoice in activeInvoice.invoice_data track by $index">
  <td class="text-center"></td>
  <td class="text-center" ng-repeat="data in invoice.items track by item.storeid">{{data.title}}</td>
  <td class="text-center"></td>
  <td class="text-center"></td>
</tr>
```

`IF YOUR STOREID IS A UNIQUE PK (so you can't have 2 storeid equal)` ...

Comment: first of all, thank for you answer federico, unfortunately this didnt worked, i think my invoice_data is wrong formatted, i cant access it at all!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT. did json encode parse. thank you guys